# read_excel is reading empty rows when engine='openpyxl'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I've switched over to Jupyter Lab recently, and discovered that pd.read_excel() now requires "engine = 'openpyxl' " in its arguments to avoid a known error in defaulting to xlrd. Unfortunately, openpyxl as an engine is introducing issues that none of my previous code accounted for.

In particular, it appears to append rows of NaN values to the end of dataframes when I import an xlsx file. I'm aware of the issue where blank rows at the start of an Excel sheet get pushed to the end of the import, and that's not the case here. I have an Excel file with multiple tabs, 16 unique column headers in the first row of each tab (and identical between tabs), and every row filled with data. Previously, in Jupyter Notebook (and without engine='openpyxl') read.excel() with sheet_name=None would create a dictionary of dataframes from each tab, reading no additional rows beyond the end of the data. Now, I get upwards of one thousand blank rows at the end of some of the dataframes.

I'm not looking forward to going through all of my old code and adding in dropna(how='all) to every import, and afraid that this might be indicative of a larger issue I'm not catching. Has anyone experienced something similar? Below are the import in Jupyter Lab of one of the tabs in question as an example, and the Excel sheet for the tab itself, with no data beyond row 5226.

Thanks for the help!

[image: Importing one tab from Jupyter Lab]

[image: The tab in question, which ends at row 5226]

Comment: are you sure all the rows are blank? i think there is some data left over that you may have copied down? try `df.dropna(how='all')`

Answer (score 0):

It was the case that with version 1.1.4 of pandas that you needed `engine="openpyxl"` but with 1.2.4 of pandas you will not need the openpyxl parameter.
So an upgrade might be worth while, but not sure if it will fix your issue.

`pip install pandas --upgrade`

to check what versions you have installed

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
print(pd.__version__)
print(openpyxl.__version__)
```